# Handler Callbacks not removed in onPause of Activity

Tags: android, handler

I have two activities(MainActivity,Sample) which extend to a custom activity(BaseActivity) i have created. I have created a handler which runs a runnable every 5 seconds in BaseActivity. In BaseActivity i have overridden onpause and onresume methods to start and stop handler whenever needed. **When i remove the callbacks of handler in onPause of BaseActivity, the handler stops but won't stop in onpause of MainActivity**. Below is the code.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

public int mInterval = 5000; 
public Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Oncreate baseactivity");
    mHandler = new Handler();       
}

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("MyApp", "every 5 secs");
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("OnPause baseactivity");
    //stopRepeatingTask();
}

void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("Onresume baseactivity");
    startRepeatingTask();
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
}

public void newpage(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Sample.class));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("onpause mainactivity");
    stopRepeatingTask();
}
```

}

```
public class Sample extends BaseActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tv.setText("sample activity");
}
```

}

The Onpause of both BaseActivity and mainActivity are called but the handler still runs if the app is closed. I hope am clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think to start thread we should use `start()` method,

and write onPause method of MainActivity in BaseActivity Itself and remove in MainActivity(i mean stopRepeating Task).

I hope it works.

Comment: handler removes it callbacks when i call stopRepeatingTask in BaseActivity  onPause method. but i want this to happen in onpause of mainActivity. As i have multiple Activities that extends baseActivity onpause is called multiple times and i dont want to stop and start the handler multiple times.